# Misinterpretation in Terminal window

Tags: terminal, macos

I have trouble with typing backlash mark in terminal on Mac. When I enter a **yen key**, which is supposed to input backslash when it is entered, gibberish characters 'ﾂ･' appeared on terminal window, instead of a backslash mark. Furthermore, it seems that the 'kernel' doesn't recognize it as backslash. On the other hand, there're no such troubles in any other applications like vim on the same machine.

I tried to fix this issue in three ways as below(WAY1~WAY3). However, none of them worked.

WAY1 : Tring stty command (ref1)

```
$ stty sane
$ ﾂ･ﾂ･ﾂ･
$ stty erase 'ﾂ･'
$ ﾂ･ﾂ
```

As shown in the above, I attempted "stty sane" command and put the key to enter backslash three times, but nothing changed. After that, I attempted "stty erase + 'backslash' key", then I found that a few things changed as below.

1. When I typed backslash key, a dot mark '･' appeared on the window instead of 'ﾂ･'.
2. When I typed delete key, gibberish characters '^?' appeared. However, after restarting the terminal system, any of these changes were initialized and showed the same problem as before setting `stty erase 'ﾂ･'`.

WAY2: Taking a look "yen key generates" from system preferences.

As the screenshot below shows, I checked "yen key generates" from system preferences. It seems not to have any problems.

[image]

WAY3: Taking a look locale functions.

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

As the above command log says, all the functions were set to `en_US.UTF-8`. So I tried another parameters as bellow. However, that didn't work, neither.

```
$ locale
LANG="jp_JP"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

Once again, I need to correct key recognition. In other words, I need to type backslash on terminal and make the kernel identify it correctly.
I would appreciate it if you could help me with solving the issue.

**About this system**

- OS: macOS Catarina v 10.15.5 (64bit)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
- The keyboard of the machine: a "A1502 Japanese JP Keyboard For Apple Macbook Pro Retina 13"(fer2).
- Terminal: Version 2.10

**References**

1. https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=659655&seqNum=13
2. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32977079344.html

attachment a